# Flutter Firebase: Get current user data from sub-collection

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Let's say a user(A) creates a collection called `ADS`. User (B) sends clicks on a button and creates a sub-collection in user (A)'s collection called `Requests`. It works alright. Now, how does user (B) get the data of user (A) in the collection `ADS`.
It's like you sending a friend request to a user and u want to know which user u have made the request to.
I have tried some codes but non is working.

//code 1 - this returns an error with a red screen as shown in the red picture

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> myRide =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collectionGroup('Requests').snapshots();

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: myRide,
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            return Center(
              child: Text(snapshot.data['Name']),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
```

//code 2 also returns results as in code 1

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> myRide =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collectionGroup('Requests').snapshots();

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: myRide,
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            return Center(
              child: Text(snapshot.data['Name']),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
```

code 3 however, returns a blank screen

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> myRide = FirebaseFirestore
      .instance
      .collection('ADS')
      .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
      .collection('Requests')
      .snapshots();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: myRide,
          builder:
              (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
            final data = snapshot.data!;
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Card(
                    child: ListTile(
                      onTap: () {},
                      title: Text(data.docs[index].get('Name')),
                    ),
                  );
                });
          }),
    );
  }
```

Any help from anyone please?

[image: code 1&2 result]
[image: code 3 result]
[image: ADS collection created by user A]
[image: Request sub-collection in ADS collection created by user B]
[image: User A uid]
[image: user b uid]

Answer (score 0):

One method would be to store the user `uid` in each document in the `ADS` collection. Then in the requests document - include the `uid` of UserB - who is making the request and the `uid` of UserA who is the person receiving the request.
When you retrieve the document from the requests collection, you can use the user `uid` to filter the documents using a query to get a list of the ADS made by UserA.
If you want clarification let me know.

---

I not familiar with Dart but checking the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#execute_a_query), try this:

```dart
// uid is the variable which holds UserA's uid
FirebaseFirestore
  .instance
  .collection("ADS").where("Uid", isEqualTo: uid).get().then(
      (querySnapshot) {
        for (var docSnapshot in querySnapshot.docs) {
          print('${docSnapshot.id} => ${docSnapshot.data()}');
        }
      },
      onError: (e) => print("Error completing: $e"),
    );
```

Comment: With storing the users uid in the respective documents I've already than that. I've included two pictures to show that. I would however be grateful if u showed me, by code, how to filter it

Comment: Check the edit above

Comment: I still don't really get it. Here you are calling for uid of the owner(user A) of the post ADS. Where does the uid of the request maker comes in? And how will user B use this info to access the post ADS?